# How do I catch Polymer events in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, dom-events

I use angularjs and polymer together, because polymer doesn't have enough material design ui elements, and angularjs has a material design project (https://material.angularjs.org) in order to implement the material design system.

HTML (`ng-app="list"` `ng-controller="showTasks"`):

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-list>
        <md-item ng-repeat="task in tasks">
            <md-item-content>
                <div class="md-tile-left">
                    <paper-icon-button icon="assignment"></paper-icon-button>
                </div>
                <div class="md-tile-content">
                    <h3>{{task.title}}</h3>
                    <h4><strong>Due: </strong>{{task.due}}</h4>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Subjects: </strong>{{task.subjects}}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <paper-ripple class="recenteringTouch" core-transitionend="" fit></paper-ripple>
            </md-item-content>
        </md-item>
    </md-list>
</md-content>
```

Script:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('list', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('showTasks', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.tasks = [];
    $http.post('/getAllTasks').success(function(response) {
        if (response.ok == 1) {
            $scope.tasks = response.result;
        }
    });
}]);
</script>
```

`paper-ripple` element has an event `core-transitionend`. It can be used in polymer-element by setting the attribute `core-transitioned={{event-handler}}` and register the handler `Polymer('element-name', {event-handler: function() {}})`.

But here angularjs will parse `{{}}` statement, and I can't register `paper-ripple` because it has been registered.

So how can I catch this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

#### Method 1:

use `directive`, and in the `link` function:

```
element.on('click', function() {
    element.on('core-transitionend', function() {
        // method 1 processing
    });
});
```

#### Method 2:

```
<paper-ripple class="recenteringTouch" ng-click="rippleClicked($event)" fit></paper-ripple>

$scope.rippleClicked = function($event) {
    angular.element($event.target).on('core-transitionend', function() {
        // method 2 processing
    });
}
```

But the two methods are not the same. For method 1, when you click on the element, hold the mouse, and release it outside the element, the `method 1 processing` will not trigger (I don't know why, it seems like the `click` event is not triggered), while method 2 will.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop angular from parsing the `{{}}` statement, try using `{{'{{}}'}}`. That might be all you need to get what you need from polymer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try:

```
<paper-ripple class="recenteringTouch" 
    core-transitionend="{{'{{event-handler}}'}}"
    fit>
</paper-ripple>
```

Comment: I'm confused... Then how do I write this function? I tried to write it both inside and outside the angular controller, but neither can capture the event.

Comment: The more I look into this, it seems like you need something like: https://github.com/GabiAxel/ng-polymer-elements (see support for additional elements at the end)

Comment: My mistake, I didn't make it clear. I had another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547156/how-to-bind-custom-events-in-angularjs/27553447#27553447 , and it could solve my problem.

Comment: But still, the solution you offered did cause AngularJS parse error.