# How to bind custom events in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, dom-events

I have an custom event `core-transitionend` (actually fired by Polymer), and I can set an event handler using `document.addEventListener()`. But what's the best practice to do it in AngularJS?

Or, I can explicitly set a handler in DOM, i.e. `<paper-ripple on-core-transitionend="enter()"></paper-ripple>`, but how to define this function in AngularJS?

Comment: create a directive which binds the event to element

Comment: @NaeemShaikh I've seen lots of posts and directive tutorials but I'm still not sure how to implement it. What does directives do here? How to pass event arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/2794/) fiddle, here I have created a custom directive which binds the event to the element,

```
angular.module('HelloApp', [])
    .directive('customDir', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',

            link: function(scope, element, attrs)      
            {
                element.bind("click",function()
            {
            alert("you clicked me");

        })
            }    


        }
    })
```

In your case you can simply bind your defined event to the element

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I didn't understand `directive` until seeing your answer!

Comment: @Melkor For less events this will work, but what you will do if you have 20 or 30 event handlers you wanna bind, you will create a custom directive for each of them?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

1. Wrap your custom element inside an `auto-binding` template.
2. Bind all handlers from angular scope to polymer scope (template element).

And that's it!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
<div ng-app="demo-app">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController">
    <template bind-events="clickMe,mouseOver" is="auto-binding">
      <paper-button raised on-tap="{{clickMe}}" on-mouseover="{{mouseOver}}">click me</paper-button>
    </template>
    <pre>
            <code>
            {[{text}]}
            </code>
            </pre>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  angular.module('demo-app', [])
    .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
    })
    .directive('bindEvents', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          eventNames = attrs.bindEvents.split(',');
          eventNames.forEach(function(eventName) {
            element[0][eventName] = scope[eventName];
          });
        }
      }
    })
    .controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
      $scope.text = '';
      $scope.clickMe = function() {
        $scope.text += '\nyou clicked me!!';
        $scope.$apply();
      };
      $scope.mouseOver = function() {
        $scope.text += '\nyou hovered me!!';
        $scope.$apply();
      }
    });
</script>
```

Or if it's not an issue to copy the whole scope you can:

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

    <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
    <div ng-app="demo-app">
      <div ng-controller="DemoController">
        <template bind-angular-scope is="auto-binding">
          <paper-button raised on-tap="{{clickMe}}" on-mouseover="{{mouseOver}}">click me</paper-button>
        </template>
        <pre>
                <code>
                {[{text}]}
                </code>
                </pre>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      angular.module('demo-app', [])
        .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
          $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
        })
        .directive('bindAngularScope', function() {
         return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    for(k in scope) {
                     if (!element[0][k]) {
                      element[0][k] = scope[k];
                     }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
          $scope.text = '';
          $scope.clickMe = function() {
            $scope.text += '\nyou clicked me!!';
            $scope.$apply();
          };
          $scope.mouseOver = function() {
            $scope.text += '\nyou hovered me!!';
            $scope.$apply();
          }
        });
    </script>
```

**Notice:** that I had to change Angular's [interpolation symbol](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider) to get them to work together.

Comment: Thank you all the same, but the thing is, I have to change the interpolation markup, which is less simpler than Naeem's answer.